# Admin Django Page not found (404)

Tags: django

Начал разбираться с Django и возник такой вот вопрос. При переходе на http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/ выдает собственно ошибку  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ошибка возникла после регистрации модели в приложении. Прикладываю собственно код.

urls.py собственно проект

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include

urlpatterns = [
  path('admin/',admin.site.urls),
  path('', include('Weather.urls')),
]
```

urls.py приложения

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
  path('', views.index),

]
```

файл модели приложения, после которого и перестала работать админка

```
from django.db import models

class City(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

   def __srt__(self):
      return  self.name
```

После создания модели, сделал собственно makemigrations, migrate и админка перестала работать(
Возможно, ошибка в urls.py приложения. Но я не знаю, как прописать(

Comment: при миграциях не было никаких ошибок?

Comment: нет, все прошло нормально

Comment: В общем, переделал все заново и заработало)